# ReactJS DropDown and PhantonJS Headless not playing nice together

Tags: reactjs, phantomjs, cucumber, bdd, poltergeist

Good day all,

I'm currently trying to run cucumber tests on a reactjs component, dropdown search selection, running in headless mode, using PhantonJS, but it is causing a weird situation that preventing me from completely these tests.

Using the following reactJs dropdown, http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/, it is the "'Github users (Async with fetch.js)'"

The current issue that is according is when the scenarios gets to it fourth example test it fails but the same code is used to pass the first three tests.

I thought it was the fourth example so I changed it around with other values and it still fails on the fourth step.

This is the code used to enter the value into the drop down search

```
find(".Select").trigger("click")

fix_overlap = %{ $('.Select-placeholder').css('z-index', -99999) }
page.execute_script(fix_overlap)

find(".Select .Select-input input").native.send_keys(with)
find(".Select-menu-outer", text: with, visible: :all, match: :first).click
```

The react control is doing async call to search for the input data from an API endpoint.

I able to run the test in a browser with no issues.

The error that is being returned from the test is that I can't found the value in the drop down.

I have added the options to the environment setup when I'm registering poltergeist,

```
options = {:js_errors => false, phantomjs_options: ['--debug=true'], debug: false }
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options) 
end
```

to see if there is an internal error that is not shown in the debug console.

I have done a page.save_screenshot to see the state just before the error and the drop down has the correct value.

**Questions**

Is there any other options that can be added to show more information/errors?

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

I'm open to any suggestions to fix this weird behaviour.

**Extra details**

gem 'poltergeist','= 1.9.0'
gem 'cucumber', '~> 2.0'

Answer (score 0):

For the "Cities (Large Dataset)" example on the linked page, the following code selects the "New York" entry for me, without resorting to using `trigger`, `execute_script` or `native`

```
with = "New York"
section = find('.section', text: 'Cities (Large Dataset)')
section.find('.Select').click
section.find('.Select-placeholder').send_keys(with)
section.find('.VirtualizedSelectOption', exact_text: with).click
```

That is using the latest Poltergeist and Capybara. Without the latest Capybara you'd probably need to pass a regex as a :text option in the last line rather than the :exact_text option (otherwise you will get multiple respones)

For the "Contributors (Async)" example

```
with = 'Craig Dallimore'
section = sess.find('.section', text: 'Contributors (Async)')
section.find('.Select').click
section.find('.Select-input input').send_keys(with.gsub(' ', '')
section.find('.Select-option', exact_text: with).click
```

will select someone

Comment: I made a change to the question as I listed the incorrect dropdown

Comment: I tried your method @Thomas Walpole, which work great for the 'Cities (Large Dataset)', but does not seem to work the for the 'Github users (Async with fetch.js)'. It seems to have an issue founding the '. VirtualizedSelectOption' value.

Comment: Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css ".VirtualizedSelectOption" with exact text craig-davis
./features/step_definitions/test_peter.rb:11:in `/^I have entered in data$/'
./features/online_v2/create_ea_business.feature:90:in `And I have entered in data'
./features/online_v2/create_ea_business.feature:86:in `And I have entered in data'
1 scenario (1 failed)
2 steps (1 failed, 1 passed)

Comment: @PeterChannon I don't have anymore time today to look at the other question, but since it's using fetch.js I would guess it's a lack of support in the version of PhantomJS being used for Promises or something like that. (PhantomJS 2.1.1 is basically equivalent to a 6 year old version of Safari)

Comment: I have attempted to run the test against the other dropdown, 'Contributors (Async)', which is not using fetch.js but it still throws the same error.

Comment: @PeterChannon I've added code for the 'Contributors' example - which produces different markup for its selections.  Also, you can't type a space in or no names are returned.